# Orphaned on inexistent entities?

Tags: datomic

Suppose I have a entity and then I retract all its attributes. Does this entity still remain in the database?

The question is because this code:

```
=> (def e (d/entity mdb 9876))
#'ww.billing/e
=> e
{:db/id 9876}
```

returns sth. that may look like an entity in the database, but I know this entity is just NOT THERE. Was never there. Perhaps it would be better to have an exception in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Entity will always return non-nil for any structurally valid entity id. Or, stated another way, having no attributes is as nonexistent as an entity can be.

For more discussion, see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/datomic/wLRRwipLrz8/e0lwtpfNop8J and https://groups.google.com/d/msg/datomic/hnOLG-fhZOU/RZvLlrGajHIJ.

Comment: They are open to changing it: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/datomic/hnOLG-fhZOU/AyJG0a5y0F4J